# VBScript RegEx - match between words

Tags: regex, vbscript

I'm having a hard time coming up with a working RegEx that words in VBScript.  I'm trying to match all text between 2 keywords:

```
(?<=key)(.*)(?=Id)
```

This throws a RegEx error in VBScript.  Id

Blob I'm matching against:

```
\"key\":[\"food\",\"real\",\"versus\",\"giant\",\"giant gummy\",\"diy candy\",\"candy\",\"gummy worm\",\"pizza\",\"fries\",\"spooky diy science\",\"spooky\",\"trapped\"],\"Id\"
```

Ideally, I'd end up with a comma delimited list like this:

```
food,real,versus,giant,giant gummy,diy candy,candy,gummy worm,pizza,fries,spooky diy science,spooky,trapped
```

but, I'd settle for all text between 2 keywords working in VBScript.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `x=Replace(Blob, "\""")` Then use `Mid`, then `Left` to lop off beginning then end. Or keep using replace. `y = Replace(x, "],Id")` then `z = Replace(y, "key:[")`.

Comment: You are dealing with JSON. Use a JSON parser. (This JSON looks like it has been double-encoded, so you would need to parse it twice.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBScript's regular expression engine doesn't support lookbehind assertions, so you'll want to do something like this instead:

```
s = "\""key\"":[\""food\"",\""real\"",\""trapped\""],\""Id\"""

'remove backslashes and double quotes from string
s1 = Replace(s, "\", "")
s1 = Replace(s1, Chr(34), "")

Set re = New RegExp
re.Pattern = "key:\[(.*?)\],Id"

For Each m In re.Execute(s1)
    list = m.Submatches(0)
Next

WScript.Echo list
```